# How to get Parent_Asset here via XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

The below is the XML I have

```
    <document>
        <businessobjects>       
            <AssetID>
                <Code>002515</Code>
                <RelatedAsset>
                    <AssetID>
                        <Code>A000507</Code>
                    </AssetID>
                </RelatedAsset>
                <DependentAsset>
                    <AssetID>
                        <Code>002519</Code>
                    </AssetID>
                </DependentAsset>

            </AssetID>
            <AssetID>
                <Code>002516</Code>
                <DependentAsset>
                    <AssetID>
                        <Code>002515</Code>
                        <RelatedAsset>
                            <AssetID>
                                <Code>A000507</Code>
                            </AssetID>
                        </RelatedAsset>
                        <DependentAsset>
                            <AssetID>
                                <Code>002519</Code>
                            </AssetID>
                        </DependentAsset>
                    </AssetID>
                </DependentAsset>
            </AssetID>
            <AssetID>
                <Code>002519</Code>
            </AssetID>
        </businessobjects>
    </document>
```

and I want this to be converted into below format

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <document>
       <businessobjects>
          <Assets>
             <Code>002515</Code>
             <Parent_Asset>****</Parent_Asset>
             <Dependent_Asset>002519</Dependent_Asset>
             <Related_Asset>A000507</Related_Asset>
          </Assets>
          <Assets>
             <Code>002516</Code>
             <Parent_Asset>*****</Parent_Asset>
             <Dependent_Asset>002515</Dependent_Asset>
             <Related_Asset/>
          </Assets>
          <Assets>
             <Code>002519</Code>
             <Parent_Asset>#####</Parent_Asset>
             <Dependent_Asset/>
             <Related_Asset/>
          </Assets>
       </businessobjects>
    </document>
```

I'm able to get other elements except for "Parent_Asset"node. 
  For 002519, Parent_Asset should be 002515 and for 002515 Parent_Asset should be 002516

The below is XSLT that I have tried.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/document">
        <document>
            <businessobjects>
        <xsl:for-each select="businessobjects/AssetID">
            <Assets>
                <Code><xsl:value-of select="child::Code[1]"/></Code>
                <Parent_Asset>

                </Parent_Asset>
                <Dependent_Asset><xsl:value-of select="DependentAsset/AssetID/Code"/></Dependent_Asset>
                <Related_Asset><xsl:value-of select="RelatedAsset/AssetID/Code"/></Related_Asset>
            </Assets>
        </xsl:for-each>

            </businessobjects>
        </document>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help. What should be the logic to get parent Asset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a key to look up `DependentAsset` elements by their code

```
<xsl:key name="Dependent" match="businessobjects/AssetID/DependentAsset"  
         use="AssetID/Code" />
```

Then you can calculate the `Parent_Asset` value like so:

```
<Parent_Asset>
     <xsl:value-of select="key('Dependent', Code)/../Code" />
</Parent_Asset>
```

So, the key gets the `Dependent` that refers to the current `Code` and you use `../Code` to get the code for the containing `AssetID`.

Comment: How to fetch Parent Asset codes, if there are multiple parents.

Comment: It is probably best to ask a new question, with an example of multiple parents assets. Thanks!